# Ember.js based dashboard

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm developing an application using ember.js and a rest API written with spring MVC. I have to create a dashboard with several widget on it. Every widget as its own behavior and will call different API method. I was thinking to have one controller subclass for each kind of widget. Then will instantiate them and will add ther views to a Container view. However ember will create a instance for each controller automatically, so is it a good path to follow? Any suggestion fom the ember.js community?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: perhaps you could have a look at http://code418.com/ember.js-dashboard/, written by @pangratz. The source code should be here: https://github.com/pangratz/dashboard

Comment: I have seen that, It contains a lot of interesting stuff but not the solution to my problem.

Comment: Ok, I mistakenly thought that it could fit to your needs :(, as there are many widgets in his project. But it seems this not the same widgets as you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than a slot for each widget, I would rather have a slot by widget area (column, ...), which would be a `ContainerView`, into which one I would dynamically add widgets views, according to user's settings.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Glad I could help. Do you need more information? If not, you can consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes, using the Route any Controller will be instantiated by the Ember, there is any way to avoid that. I would like to have one type of Controller for each Type of Widget. So If I have two Widget with the Same type, I will have two instances of that Controller type.

Comment: I think you should try to avoid coupling "dynamic" widgets instances to "static" implementation code. The best would be to have all the (specific/parametric) state of your widget hold into a model, and the (generic) behavior hold by the controller. So you may have a single stateless controller instance animating several widgets.

Answer (score 5):

Your ideas sound pretty good.

There are certainly many ways to structure this. I would perhaps suggest making a DashboardView and DashboardController, and in its template, have several [outlets](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet), one for each widget "slot":

```
{{outlet topWidgetView}}
{{outlet leftWidgetView}}
...
```

Then in the router, in the dashboard route's `connectOutlets` method, connect the widgets after you've instantiated the dashboard:

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('dashboard');

router.get('dashboardController').connectOutlet({
  outletName: 'topWidgetView',
  name: 'fooWidget'
});
router.get('dashboardController').connectOutlet({
  outletName: 'leftWidgetView',
  name: 'barWidget'
});
```

Comment: I wonder if I would use outlets here, since the page seems to be static, and widgets don't switch. But this solution has the advantage of beeing flexible

Comment: It is not the case, because each area can have multiple Widgets. Basically each widget have x and y coordinate: x specifies the Area and y the order in that Area.